# what does it mean when we see people calling widget in dart?

Tags: flutter, widget

I have seen many times people calling widget. sth inside the code.

May I know what it is actually doing?

For example code below, (highlighted part is my confusion)

---

```
class _MyOwnClassState extends State<MyOwnClass> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ListTile(
      title: Container(
        child: Column(children: makeWidgetChildren(**widget.jsonObject)**),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flutter's `StatefulWidget`, we have the following architecture.

You have a `StatefulWidget` like this,

```
class MyOwnClass extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState () => _MyOwnClassState();
}
```

And you have a `State` class for your `StatefulWidget` like this,

```
class _MyOwnClassState extends State<MyOwnClass> {
}
```

Now, `State` class is meant to house variables that tend to change in order for your UI to be rebuilt.

So you can have variables in your `State` that you can update using `setState`.

But what if you had some data that doesn't change and you want to avoid putting them inside the `State` class.

That's where your `StatefulWidget` comes to play.

You can store variables in your `MyOwnClass` and the `widget` variable inside the `State` class gives you a way to access them.

For example,

```
class MyOwnClass extends StatefulWidget {
  int numberThatDoesntChange = 1;

  State createState () => _MyOwnClassState();
}
```

You can access them in your `State` class like this,

```
class _MyOwnClassState extends State<MyOwnClass> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('$widget.numberThatDoesntChange');
  }
}
```

Apart from this, your `StatefulWidget` has many more internal instance members that you can access inside of your `State` class using the `widget` variable.

Comment: this explained well

Comment: Glad to have helped @hose. Do consider accepting my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: May i know how to do this action? I would like to do it. In addition, may i know where can I check more about widget varible? Since I dont see it anywhere, so sometimes I may find it struggle to master it.

Comment: Hi There, check this for accepting answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. For the `widget` variable, just ctrl + click on the `widget` in your code. it will redrirect you to the documenation

Answer (score 0):

The `widget` refers to the actual view that renders on the screen. It extends the `StatefulWidget` class of the flutter framework and overrides the `createState()` method. The `createState()` method is used to create the instance of state class. We will look into `createState()`.

The `state class` is used to maintain the state of the widget so that it can be rebuilt again. It extends the State class of the flutter framework and overrides the `build method`.

The framework calls `build() method` again and again whenever `setState()` method is called. The `setState()` method notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed and it should be rebuilt. Suppose we change the value of text in `StatefulWidget` then we need to call `setState()`.

Answer (score 0):

***Edit*** As Nisanth pointed outh in his comment - I missed your question completely; please ignore the below....

Let me try my answer, I don't think others are getting your point.

In your exapmle, Column(children: x) expect a list of Widgets.

You have two options - either provide this list directly:

```
class _MyOwnClassState extends State<MyOwnClass> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ListTile(
      title: Container(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[SomeWidget()]),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Or if you have more complex code that generates widget - based on input parameters, or you have the same widget generated multiple times and you want to avoid the code duplication - you would create the separate function to do the job.

Something like:

```
class _MyOwnClassState extends State<MyOwnClass> {

  List<Widget> makeWidgetChildren(int param) {
     /*
    some very complex logic here
    /*
    if (param>3 && param<4) {
        return List<Widget>.generate(4, (index)=>SomeWidget1(index));
    } else {
        return <Widget>[Center()];
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ListTile(
      title: Container(
        child: Column(children: makeWidgetChildren(**widget.jsonObject)**),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

So basically, it is just to make the code nicer; and to avoid having code repeated over and over again in the build function.

Comment: This seems to be heavily diverting from the main point, OP wanted to understand what does it mean when some people are calling `widget.something`. This answer however seems to be explaining `why create extra functions like makeWidgetChildren`. That's not what OP was referring to.

Comment: Yes you are right; I read his question again.